# mouse support in Midnight Commander in MSYS2

Tags: msys2, mc

How can you enable mouse support in in Midnight Commander in MSYS2?

Currently when I click the options menu there appear only control sequences like `6;1M6;1m` in the console.

When I ssh into a Linux box from the same MSYS2 bash shell, Midnight Commander works with mouse support. So I guess I need to change a local Midnight Commander setting.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with current [2019-08] MSYS2 and mc, mouse control is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue. I switched the terminal emulation of cmd.exe (under options/terminal) to "xterm-vt220". Now it works

Comment: I want to confirm that this solved my problem with mouse input in mc on msys2 20230127.